# PHP include searching in the wrong place

Tags: php

So I have a web application hosted on a site. The web root (I.E. the files the client can access) is the public_html folder. However, I need to include files outside of the public_html folder. I do this using php include. I get an error no such file or directory. When it shows me the path it is still looking in the public_html folder, which is not where I need it looking.
The code looks like this:

```
<?php include('../eCommerceCore/shoppingCart.php');?>
```

I need it to look up one level but it will not search outside of public_html. Also, the file containing the line of code shown above is in the public_html folder if that helps.

Comment: did you check file directory and path was correct?

Comment: This could be related to PHP's `open_basedir` configuration settings. It restricts PHP's ability to open files outside of a certain directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the current directory isn't what you expect it to be, such as when you include a file from an included file.

I like to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on my includes so that I can always reference them absolutely from the root of my site:

```
<?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."../eCommerceCore/shoppingCart.php");

?>
```

Or this way you can try

```
<?php
    include "../eCommerceCore/shoppingCart.php";       
?>
```

If your includes directory is above your document root, you can use .. to still reference from the root.

Comment: It still throws the same error. So ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) is referencing the public_html folder. Is there anyway to change that?

Comment: @MattComeaux, what are permission do you have to that folder

Comment: The permissions are 0755 for the folder containing the files and 0644 for the files I need to include.

Comment: Oh and if you ment the public_html folder it is 0750.

Comment: still didn't work. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is still referencing  home4/user/public_html I need it to reference home4/user/eCommerceCore. To help the full error I am getting is: include(/home4/user/public_html/eCommerceCore/shoppingCart.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/user/public_html/eCommerce/index.php on line 3. I don't wan't it looking for the files I want in the public_html folder.